# select <label> in <td> come immediately after <input> thas this in <td> too in CSS

Tags: css, tags, selector

i Write this code

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="name" value="value"></td>
           <td><label for="id">LABLE</label></td> /*SELECT THIS LABEL*/
       </tr>
</table>
```

I need to select td[1] to work on it in the DOM and CSS.
how can i do it?

Comment: try `label[for="id"] { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to target the label item in your HTML, the easiest way is to apply a class or id to it, like `<label class="myLabel" for="id">LABLE</label>`. Then you can target .myLabel in your CSS to be able to manipulate it.

Comment: Hi and sorry for my bad English. No I don't want use id, really i try for create my customized checkbox, and it will be use at a page with table formated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the selector

```
`:nth-child()`
```

In your particular example, you to select the checkbox, you can use:

```
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  // put your styling here
}
```

You could always add classes or ids to anything you want to select. You can then target elements in CSS or JS.

In CSS you can do it as such

```
.className {
  // styling here
}
```

In Javascript you can do the follow:

```
document.querySelector('.className');
```

If you are using an id, you use `#idName` instead.